# Односложный

Tags: семантика

Как вы понимаете слово "односложный"?

Односложный ответ, вопрос, ругательство?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Односложный ответ - очень короткий, практически одним словом. С другими словами не употребляю, кажется...

Comment: А как бы поняли фразу "он использовал односложное оскорбление"?
наводящий вопрос. "Односложное слово" - это какое?

Comment: Про односложное слово все понятно. Односложное - из одного слога. Значит, короткое. Происходит перенос значения. Главное - короткое, а слогов может и больше.

Comment: Итак. В правилах форума любителей русского слова (назовем так) написано "Запрещен [мат и] односложные оскорбления". Как это понимать? На всяк случай: многосложные не запрещены, вернее о них ничего не говорится. Про мат - это просто другой параграф.

Comment: Знаете, я когда писала ответ, у меня была одна мысль... Но я решила, что я ошибаюсь или что-то путаю. Мне почему-то пришло на ум: односложное=однозначное. Как видно, не только у меня значения этих двух  похожих слов смешиваются. Это, на мой взгляд,  неверное употребление. Но,видно, на форуме тоже имели в виду нечто подобное.Хотя почему бы не написать просто "не допускаются оскорбления": ни явные (однозначные, односложные, ясные), ни завуалированные и не всем понятные.

Comment: Браво, Ларf!!!
Пожалуй, это единственное разумное объяснение...
Я тоже подозревал, что слово употреблено в необычном смысле, но не мог понять, в каком. Голову сломал, почему "многоэтажные" разрешены, а "односложные" - нет.

"Однозначное", впрочем, тоже не тот термин... Там, видимо, речь о том, что запрещены прямые ("Ты - козел"), а косвенные ("Я бы назвал тебя козлом, если бы не правила форума") не оговариаются... Как-то так...

Comment: Я и во втором Вашем предложении вижу оскорбление, причем совершенно однозначное.

Comment: Не к месту, но не знаю, где выразить недоумение? Кто это поставил мне СТОЛЬКО плюсов за давние вопросы, причем за несколько вопросов в минуту?
___________________
Посмотрела профили, поняла кто. Поняла, что все, наверное, читано раньше. Не поняла, почему плюсы поставлены именно сейчас, разом, а не сразу после ответов?

Comment: >Я и во втором Вашем предложении вижу оскорбление, причем совершенно однозначное.  
  
А вот это уже вопрос сложный... Оскорбление есть, согласен, но как его трактовать, по какой "статье"... Это вопрос трактовки. 
А если "Я хотел назвать NN козлом, но не смог"? "Ровно в 17:00 мне пришло в голову, что он - козел, и я целый час не мог отогнать от себя эту мысль"... и проч. 

>Кто это поставил мне СТОЛЬКО плюсов за давние вопросы, причем за несколько вопросов в минуту?  
  
Не я ))) Это бывает. Кто-то просматривает вопросы - и лепит подряд "плюсы".
Хотя да. Перебор, пожалуй.

Answer (score 1):

Как правило, вполне буквально, состоящий из одного слова или, реже, одного слога.

Односложный ответ ограничивается трио *да, нет, не знаю*".
Под односложным вопросом, я понял бы вопрос, предполагающий односложный ответ, или серию вопросов *Что?*, *Как?* и т.д.
Под односложным ругательством, что-то вроде *Чёрт!*, *Блин!* и т.п.

Правда последние два примера мне слышать не доводилось.

Comment: >Односложный ответ ограничивается трио да, нет, не знаю".

"Так точно, никак нет, не могу знать"? - годится?

>Под односложным ругательством, что-то вроде Чёрт!, Блин! и т.п.  
  
Вы считаете число ***слогов***? "Сука", пардон, или "паскуда" - подходит?

Comment: 1. Вполне годятся и *так точно...*. Главное - однозначный чёткий смысл, без уточнений и раскрытия.

2 Нет, количество слогов не важно, важна скорее функция междометия. Если попав молотком по пальцу человек закричит,- "Гидроэлектростанция!", посчитать это односложным ругательством я вполне могу. Если ругательство в пустоту - односложное, если обзывают конкретную личность - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Я  думаю,  что  односложное  это  из  одного  слога ( предполагается,  что  люди  знают ).  А  если  слогов  больше  -  краткое.  А  если  совсем  много - трёхэтажное.  И  с  вопросами  также: да,  нет - односложные,  никак  нет - краткое.

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрались вроде.

Comment: Не  сомневался  даже,  но  разговоров  много.